# disable multiselect on bootstrap collapse buttons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to find a way to implement bootstrap buttons which will show collapsible content without allowing the content of more than one button to show at any time.

I can get the buttons to trigger collapsible content but I cant find a way to stop them both being un-collapsed at the same time:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button 1
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
    Button 2
  </a>
</p>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Here is some example text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Here is some example text, too
  </div>
</div>
```

js fiddle demo here:  https://jsfiddle.net/hzs68sne/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve looks like the [collapse accordion](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp#accordion).

To do this with your current setup, you can wrap the entire group in a single `.panel div` and make use of the `data-parent` attribute.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" data-parent="#container">
          Button 1
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" data-parent="#container">
          Button 2
        </a>
    </p>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-block">
        Here is some example text
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-block">
        Here is some example text, too
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gbfb32z9/

Keep in mind:

- The `.panel div` needs to be a direct child of the `data-parent` element.
- The `.collapse` elements are direct children of a `.panel` element.